# Torch running out of memory issues

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

Using Torch, I am trying to load a large set of images into the program. But as I approach 50'000 images the kernel starts to crash which I assume is due to memory limitation. A minimal example of my code (results using 20,000 images):

```
print(f"Before starting to loop: {psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 3} GB")

X_data = []
y_data = []
for path in paths:
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    X_data.append(np.array(img/255, dtype=np.uint8))

print(f"Before convert to numpy: {psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 3} GB")

X_data = np.array(X_data)

print(f"Before shuffle: {psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 3} GB")

shuffle_index = np.random.permutation(X_data.shape[0])

X_data = X_data[shuffle_index]

print(f"Before Convert to tensor: {psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 3} GB")

X_data = torch.Tensor(X_data).view(-1, 3, 128, 128)

print(f"Before save: {psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 3} GB")

torch.save(X_data, f"X_data.pt")

print(f"After save: {psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 3} GB")
```

Gives the following memory information:

```
Before starting to loop:    0.26 GB
Before convert to numpy:    1.29 GB
Before shuffle:             2.28 GB
Before Convert to tensor:   2.28 GB
Before save:                5.22 GB
After save:                 4.14 GB
```

Is there something I am doing inefficiently? I have tried playing around with not using the intermediate steps but both `torch.cat` and `numpy.append` are just way too slow.

Is it instead recommended to store data as files in batch sizes and then load the data whenever that batch is going to be fed through the network? I can not find any beginner guides on how to do that and also, 50'000 images of size 128*128*3 seem to be a rather small amount of images to be causing issues...

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

1. Use in place shuffles instead of `np.random.permutation` to create indexes. The latter will create new arrays while the former will not:

```
np.random.default_rng().shuffle(X_data, 0)
```

2. Use [`torch.from_numpy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.from_numpy.html) to create the Tensor instead of `torch.Tensor`. In this way, the Tensor created will share memory with the numpy array:

```
X_data = torch.from_numpy(X_data).view(-1, 3, 128, 128)
```

---

If you want to shuffle multiple arrays of the same length in the same order, you can use the same seed to build random generator (if you don't want the results to be reproducible, you can first use the default random generator to generate the seed to be used):

```
>>> a1 = np.arange(10).repeat(2).reshape(-1, 2)
>>> a2 = np.arange(10)
>>> np.random.default_rng(12345).shuffle(a1, 0)
>>> np.random.default_rng(12345).shuffle(a2, 0)
>>> a1
array([[4, 4],
       [8, 8],
       [1, 1],
       [3, 3],
       [7, 7],
       [9, 9],
       [6, 6],
       [0, 0],
       [2, 2],
       [5, 5]])
>>> a2
array([4, 8, 1, 3, 7, 9, 6, 0, 2, 5])
```

Comment: Thank you! On point 1, maybe my minimal example is too small but the reason why I generate the index first is to be able to shuffle a y_data array in the same order.

Comment: Will default_rng shuffle two arrays of the same length in the same order every time?

Comment: @JakobVinkas Updated a solution to shuffle multiple arrays in the same order.

Comment: The from_array made a big difference but I then realized that it changed the tensor from being a float to a uint8 since the numpy array was a uint8. When using the tensor I need it to be float again I think. Isnt there some dataloader you can use to only load the batch needed or something?

Comment: @JakobVinkas [DataLoader](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html) may be helpful.